# How to rebind select command in 7-zip?

Tags: 7-zip

In 7-zip, there's a very useful command

```
Edit -> Select
```

which is bind to `Grey +` , that is, the numeric keyboard `+`

I'm using a laptop, it is unconvinent to access numeric keyboard key.

Is it possible to rebind it to another key, say, `alt-f`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Alternately, you could install a keyboard macro application like [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). In AutoHotKey, add the following to your script (immediately before the line which reads, `return`):

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class FM
  F8::SendInput {NumpadAdd}
```

This will bind the action to the <kbd>F8</kbd> key; which is otherwise unused in 7zip FM.

Comment: Thank you! The script works very well. 7-zip's file manager is very good, if not better than others.

Comment: @Nick I suppose, I rarely use it though. I do use 7zip from the command line a lot and have do a lot of testing with it. In my experience, it compresses about 15% better than RAR and RAR is about 10% better than ZIP. It is also a about equally as much slower though. All tests being done at maximum compression given the default dictionary sizes. 7zip is especially good at shrinking the one thing I need shrunk the most, which is ISO images. ZIP is basically useless at this, RAR typically only gets around 4%-10% compression. 7zip is closer to 10%-15%.

Comment: Wow, thank you for telling me these figures - they're quite useful from a user's perspective.